# How to detect what kotlin flow is triggering combine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

Is it possible to detect what flow is emitting values in combine operator?

```
val flow = combine (flow1, flow2, flow3){
data1, data2, data3->

//Need to detect what flow is emitting

}
```

Comment: You can perhaps add `var lastEmmited` and do `combine( flow1.onEach {  lastEmitted = flow1 }, flow2.onEach... )` etc to keep track of it, but you'd get flow3 as initial value most of the time.